# Recommended IP ranges for Dev SAN with 2 x switches

Tags: iscsi, qnap, unifi

I am setting up a small Dev environment with 5 hosts, 2 ubiquity switches and a qnap NAS.   One switch for the normal TCP traffic and one for iSCSI.  I was wondering the recommendation for management of the switches.  Unifi switches are managed by a external controller - in this case just a VM on one of the hosts.   I already have all the equipment, so alternate equipment is not an option.

```
QNAP <-Fibre-> Unify switch <-Eth10-> Host(s) <-Eth2.5-> Unify switch <-The World->

QNAP <8.8.1.x/30> Unify switch <8.8.2.x/27> Host(s) <-192.168.1.x/24> Unify switch <-The World->
```

I don't want unnecessary management traffic over the iScsi switch and was considering just keeping management disconnected until I need it (or a recommendation).  Is there a recommendation that will allow me to extract maximum performance, while still allowing management of BOTH switches or just leave it disconnected.

To be clear, there is no redundant iScsi links and a unifi backup / restore will be the likely solution in this case.

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Why are you worrying about performance impact from mgmt traffic?

Comment: Possibly I am worrying too much, but as I understand it is not good form to really put anything on iScsi other than iScsi traffic.  The ubiquity not having it's own management on the switch complicates things a little, in that you need to connect another device to manage the switch (other than using a console cable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a dedicated management port on the switch = two VLANs, one for management, one for iSCSI.

Management traffic can be neglected for iSCSI performance. Even if it does hit the CPU a tiny bit, it doesn't impact normal forwarding on a modern switch.